# Can't prevent default form submission while using ajax for form submission

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee

I am trying to submit a form(which also contains a fileinput) using ajax , everything works fine but I can't prevent default form submission using return false and e.preventdefault() method.

This is my jquery ajax submission code :

```
var formrequest = $('#Request_Search');

formrequest.submit(function (e)     
    {       
         alert("form submit called");
        var fileInput = $('#file'); 
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        data = formrequest.serialize();
        data.append('file', file);
       $.ajax({
          type: formrequest.attr('method'),
          url: formrequest.attr('action'),
          data: data,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function (data) 
          {
            alert("Reached")
          },
            error:function()
            {
                 alert("failure");

             }   
        });        
       return false;     //I have tried e.preventDefault() also.But that also does't help   
    });
```

Code for my form :

```
<form id="Request_Search" method="post" action="queryupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">

<div class="form-group" id="filediv">

        <label for="file">Upload your Fasta File:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="file" id="file"   required accept=".txs,.fasta,.fa">    
</div>


  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="file">Enter you email id:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="Enter emailid so we can send you outputs" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="file">Enter Percent Identity value :</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" name="pident" id="pident" placeholder="Enter value for pident" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Enter Mismatch percentage :</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100"  class="form-control" name="mismatch" id="mismatch" placeholder="Enter values for % mismatch expected" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="file">Enter query coverage :</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" name="querycoverage" id="mismatch" placeholder="Enter values for query coverage" required>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="form-group"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" i class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"></input>     
</div>

 </form>
```

In servlet's dopost() method :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
     {
     PrintWriter po = response.getWriter();
     po.write("Check text");
     }
```

From google Chrome devloper tools.If it can help in anyway:

[image]
My servlet is being called properly , but I am redirected to next page and result on that page.how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because you have given "action" and "method" attributes in your form tag aswell. Something like

```
<form method="post" action="/servletName"> 
  ... 
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form
```

This is evident from these 2 lines in your javascript, where you are fetching url from the form tag's attribute itself.

```
  ...
  type: formrequest.attr('method'),
  url: formrequest.attr('action'),
  ...
```

What this would be doing is, when a user clicks submit button, 2 calls would be fired(one ajax call and other to your servlet, from form's action attribute)

**Proposed Fix:**

- Remove form tag's "action" and "method" attribute
- Hardcode your "type" and "url" in ajax code

.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/servletName",
      data: data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) 
      {
        alert("Reached")
      },
        error:function()
        {
             alert("failure");

         }   
    });
```

Comment: Something's not right here.  The submit event is cancellable, so nothing should have hit the server while the handler is still running, otherwise it wouldn't have a chance to call preventDefault.  Yet, that's exactly the behavior I'm seeing here.  The handler should be cancelling the main submission event by returning false (which it can't do if the post has already hit the server), so the only call that should be made is the ajax request.  Something is definitely not right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false` inside ajax success

```
  success: function (data) 
  {
    alert("Reached");
    return false;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function like this in your form than if its returns false its stop form submission

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative

You can move the submit button out of the  tag and make it like a normal button.

Then add the form submit code in the onclick event of the button.